# how to show that when an edge is removed from K5, the resluting subgraph is planar.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

this question might be simple to others, but I'm stuck on this question. "prove that when I deleted an edge from $K5$, it has planar sub-graph .

So, I know that G is planar if and only if G contains no sub-division of $K5$ or $K3,3$. So that means when I delete an edge from K5, I no loger have sub-division of K5 and therefore, the subgraph is planar. But how do I show that explicitly that when I remove edge from $K5$, it will have planar subgraph? (I think this question is somewhat related to Kuratowski's theorem)

Comment: Why not show a particular planar drawing of it?

Comment: Indeed.  You have seen a planar drawing of $K_4$ I expect (a triangle with a vertex in the center of the triangle).  Form the graph in question by adding one more vertex outside of the triangle and attaching edges from all vertices on (but not in) the triangle to the outside point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key observation is that all graphs of "$K_5$ with one edge removed" are isomorphic.

To this end, you can just start with a picture of $K_5$, remove any one edge, and then try to re-draw what results as a planar graph. The important component is understanding why this approach generalizes enough to prove the graph is planar for *any* single edge-removal.

To this end, here is a picture that came up after googling **K5 graph planar**:

[image]

By way of a similar argument, you can reason about $K_{3,3}$ and draw a convincing picture:

[image]

(From wikipedia [**here**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/K33_one_crossing.svg).)

Without loss of generality, the removed edge could be one of the two that cross above.

Comment: You more or less duplicated my answer,so it's yours. Good job.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Thanks; I expect most would solve it this way (and really it is just Kelvin Soh's comment depicted).

Comment: If it ain't broke,don't fix it-math and life are both hard enough.